# Spring Data Mongodb Convert Document Falsely

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have a document structure which has some generic class. For writing to mongodb everything is fine. But when reading documents from mongodb spring data converts document into object falsely. It converts a subdocument with another type. Both types (actual subcollection type and falsely converted type) are inherit from same abstract class.

Model Classes:(getter setters are generated by lombok )

```
@Data
public abstract class CandidateInfo {

    private String _id;
}

@Data
public class CandidateInfoContainer<E extends CandidateInfo> {

    private String _id;

    private int commentCount = 0;

    @Valid
    private List<E> values = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Data
public class Responsibility extends CandidateInfo {

    @NotNull
    private String responsibilityId;

    @ReadOnlyProperty
    private String responsibilityText;
}

@Data
public class Experience extends CandidateInfo {

    @Valid
    private CandidateInfoContainer<Responsibility> responsibilities;
}

@Document
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@Data
public class Candidate {

    private String _id;

    @Valid
    private CandidateInfoContainer<Experience> experiences;
}
```

And if you create a mongoRepository like below:

```
@Repository
public interface CandidateRepository extends MongoRepository<Candidate,String>{
}
```

And use it like:

```
@Autowired
private CandidateRepository candidateRepository;

Candidate candidate = candidateRepository.findOne("documentId");
```

Then spring data mongo mapping converter creates **candidates.experiences.responsibilities.values** list as **Experince** list but it should be **Responsibility** list.

You can find a demo project in [this link](https://github.com/barbakini/mongodb-buggy) and more information about the issue. Can anyone point out what is wrong? Otherwise i have to write my own converter(demo has one)

If there is any unclear thing, you can ask.

Thanks.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: When you persist a document, are you able to see `_class` elements in mongo?

Comment: That's the text of the standard close reason attached to your question. The **bold** sections are meant to draw your attention to the fact that linking to "external" codebases and not actually "narrowing down" the problem to a "specific" area, is not really sufficient for asking a question here. You should at least attempt a "minimal example" that demonstrates and reproduces the problem you encounter. Such a list **always** fits in the question space here, and **almost always** answers the question for you during the process of writing it.

Comment: Hi @DarshanMehta, for actual document I can see the _class element. And for the problematic subdocument again I can see the _class element. Writing converter is working fine but reading is working falsely

Comment: As per [Spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo-template.type-mapping), mapper should be able to map to correct class with `_class` attribute. However, if the class can't be instantiated then it falls back to default type which I believe is what's happening in this case.

Comment: Hi @DarshanMehta there seems no reason to instantiate fail for the desired class(it is used some other part of the document as subdocument too and no problem for them) Additionally fell back class is in same level with the desired class(they both inherited from same abstract class. Beside that there is no inheritance between them)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I open an issue in spring-data-mongo [here](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACMNS-1135). Appareantly I caught a bug! Thanks everyone